# Splitting is not working as expected in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, split

I tried the following query to split the string and need to insert in table as separte column. My string is as below:

```
'link:http://www.google.com,description:Google,link:http://www.google.co.uk,description:GoogleUK'
```

Expected output in table:

```
link                    description
http://www.google.com   Google
http://www.google.co.uk GoogleUK
```

I tried the following query but it is not working:

```
 select  regexp_substr('link:http://www.google.com,description:Google,link:http://www.google.co.uk,description:GoogleUK',
                  '(link:)?(.*?)(,link:|$)(description:)?(.*?)(,description:|$)', 1, level, null, 2)
      from    dual
      connect by level <= regexp_count('link:http://www.google.com,description:Google,link:http://www.google.co.uk,description:GoogleUK','link:description:');
```

Comment: It would be much more efficient to work with a standardized format for transmitting such data. Can you ask the data provider to send it in JSON format, for example? Then the problem would be much easier.

Answer (score 1):

You are counting the occurrence of the string literal 'link:description:' - but that doesn't appear anywhere in your example value. You also need two substring to get the two values, something like:

```
select  regexp_substr('link:http://www.google.com,description:Google,link:http://www.google.co.uk,description:GoogleUK',
                      '(link:)(.*?)(,description:|$)', 1, level, null, 2) as link,
        regexp_substr('link:http://www.google.com,description:Google,link:http://www.google.co.uk,description:GoogleUK',
                      '(description:)(.*?)(,link:|$)', 1, level, null, 2) as description
from    dual
connect by level <= regexp_count('link:http://www.google.com,description:Google,link:http://www.google.co.uk,description:GoogleUK', 'link:');
```

| LINK | DESCRIPTION |
| --- | --- |
| http://www.google.com | Google |
| http://www.google.co.uk | GoogleUK |

If your comma-separated string is coming from a table and you need to process multiple rows, then if each row has a unique ID you can expand the connect-by to deal with that, but it needs a bit of a hack to prevent looping. For example, if your table was called `t` and had (unique) `id` and `str` columns you could do something like:

```
select  regexp_substr(str, '(link:)(.*?)(,description:|$)', 1, level, null, 2) as link,
        regexp_substr(str, '(description:)(.*?)(,link:|$)', 1, level, null, 2) as description
from    t
connect by id = prior id
and     prior dbms_random.value is not null
and     level <= regexp_count(str, 'link:');
```

Or you can use recursive subquery factoring:

```
with rcte (str, cnt, lvl, link, description) as (
  select str,
         regexp_count(str, 'link:'),
         1,
         regexp_substr(str, '(link:)(.*?)(,description:|$)', 1, 1, null, 2),
         regexp_substr(str, '(description:)(.*?)(,link:|$)', 1, 1, null, 2)
  from   t
  union all
  select str,
         regexp_count(str, 'link:'),
         lvl + 11,
         regexp_substr(str, '(link:)(.*?)(,description:|$)', 1, lvl + 1, null, 2),
         regexp_substr(str, '(description:)(.*?)(,link:|$)', 1, lvl + 1, null, 2)
  from   rcte
  where  lvl < cnt
)
select link,
       description
from   rcte;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=0b07ed43c800fd6a08312c229e7ed6e3)